# Contenteditable field onchange event add date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

HTML:

```
 <p id="bon_date"  class="inline" style="color:#0000ff;" contenteditable="true" onchange="add7day()"> enter date </p>
```

javascript:

```
     function add7day() {
         var str = document.getElementById(#bon_date).value;
         var startdate = str.split("/");
         var month = parseInt(stardate[0], 10);
         var day = parseInt(stardate[1], 10);
         var o_month = parseInt(stardate[0], 10);
         var o_day = parseInt(stardate[1], 10);
         if (month == 1 | month == 3 | month == 5 | month == 7 | month == 8 | month == 10 | month == 12) {
           if ((day + 7) > 31) {
             month = month + 1;
             day = day + 7 - 31;
           } else {
             day = day + 7;
           }
           document.getElementById(#bon_date).innerHTML = o_month + "/" + o_day + "~" + month + "/" + day;

         } else {
           if ((day + 7) > 30) {
             month = month + 1;
             day = day + 7 - 30;
           } else {
             day = day + 7;
           }

           document.getElementById(#bon_date).innerHTML = o_month + "/" + o_day + "~" + month + "/" + day;

         }
```

I can get the string from input type field but I can`t get it from contenteditable field.

and when it runs to `var month = parseInt(stardate[0],10);`  I get errors like:

> stardate[0] is not define..

I want input a date by manual and gets the date after 7 days.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `element.textContent` instead of `element.value`?

Comment: I mean like this: `str=document.getElementById('bon_date').textContent; `

Comment: `str=document.getElementById().value;` ^_^ notice something wrong there?

Comment: there are many mistakes in your code . var str=document.getElementById().value; and what is X in your code

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/MamdouhFreelancer/gmvhLjup/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, where to begin.

I'm not going to question the use of a `contenteditable` element instead of an `input type="text"` or `input type="date"` element, I'm just going to fix your JavaScript.

Elements with `contenteditable` are not converted to `input` elements or `textareas`, so they do not have a `value` property, but they do have a `textContent` because they're otherwise normal HTML nodes which can have text nodes.

Elements with `contenteditable` also do not emit an `onchange` or `change` event when their text content is edited. You could listen for the `input` event, but that would break your code, because your function would constantly amend the element's contents every time the user pressed a key—making it practically unusable.

The next best thing to the `onchange` event is the `onblur`/`blur` event, so we'll use that. This means when the user focuses off the event, i.e. clicks outside it (or presses the tab key etc) the function will fire.

---

`stardate[0]` comes back as `undefined` because you didn't define a variable called `stardate`, you defined `startdate`. Similarly, none of the code works at all without getting the `bon_date` element, which in this case would be done by fixing your code so `document.getElementById()` is given a parameter `'bon_date'` (not `'#bon_date'`, because `document.getElementById` does not use CSS selectors).

```js
// Store the element in a variable so we don't have to keep writing this crap out.
var bd = document.getElementById('bon_date');

// Listen for the blur event by adding an event listener in JavaScript.
// You could also use an 'onblur=' attribute on the element in question.
bd.addEventListener('blur', add7day, false);

function add7day() {
  // Get the element's text content.
  var str = bd.textContent;

  // You could just say startdate = bd.textContent.split("/") and leave out out the str variable.
  var startdate = str.split("/");
   
  var month = parseInt(startdate[0], 10);
  var day = parseInt(startdate[1], 10);
  var o_month = parseInt(startdate[0], 10);
  var o_day = parseInt(startdate[1], 10);
   
  if (month == 1 | month == 3 | month == 5 | month == 7 | month == 8 | month == 10 | month == 12) {
    if ((day + 7) > 31) {
      month = month + 1;
      day = day + 7 - 31;
    } else {
      day = day + 7;
    }

    // no need to use innerHTML, just amend the textContent again
    bd.textContent = o_month + "/" + o_day + "~" + month + "/" + day;

  } else {
    if ((day + 7) > 30) {
      month = month + 1;
      day = day + 7 - 30;
    } else {
      day = day + 7;
    }

   bd.textContent = o_month + "/" + o_day + "~" + month + "/" + day;

  }
}
```

```html
<p id="bon_date" class="inline" style="color:#0000ff;" contenteditable="true"> Enter date (MM/DD) </p>
```

That gets your code *working*. Sort of. You should think about validating user input to make sure it's a valid date (not the 1000th day of a 50th month) etc. [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is a very handy JavaScript library to use when dealing with dates and times.

Comment: Thanks !! I am really appreciate because I am working with this problem for almost  2 days.I`ve never used textContent before and this really helps me

Comment: No problem! Glad to help.